# Null Value appear in DataGridView in after new column added

Tags: c#

My Datagridview have one name column. I am trying to add one image column with that datagridview. Once I add the image column it made that name column as null. Please refer the below code:

```
public void call(string usr)
{
    user = usr;
    queryString = "select NAME 'Name' from ADK_MY_PRODSYSSECGROUP";
    try
    {
        specdataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, con);
        specds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        specdataadapter.Fill(specds, "REPORT_Table");
        dgvdisp.DataSource = specds;
        dgvdisp.DataMember = "REPORT_Table";
        dgvdisp.Columns[dgvdisp.ColumnCount - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        con.Close();

        if (user == "Secgrp")
        {
            DataGridViewImageColumn set = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            set.Name = "set";
            set.HeaderText = "Settings";
            dgvdisp.Columns.Insert(1, set);
            for (int rows = 0; rows < dgvdisp.Rows.Count; rows++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dgvdisp.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DispMessageBox disp = new DispMessageBox("Fail to retrieve data. Please try again");
        disp.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public void calling()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

    for (int rows = 0; rows < dgvdisp.Rows.Count; rows++)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select SETTINGS from ADK_MY_PRODSYSSECGROUP where NAME='" + Convert.ToString(dgvdisp.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value) + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.GetInt32(0) == 1)
                {
                    Image image = Properties.Resources.start;
                    //set.Image = image;
                    dgvdisp.Rows[rows].Cells["set"].Value = image;
                }
                if (reader.GetInt32(0) == 0)
                {
                    Image image = Properties.Resources.finish;
                    //set.Image = image;    
                    dgvdisp.Rows[rows].Cells["set"].Value = image;
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Here in the call method, dgvdisp datagridview shows the value, But when I tried to get the value from calling method, the datagridview shows null value when I retrieve name field.

Please suggest...

Comment: I dont see anywhere in your code you adding values to the new column...

Comment: Hi BugFinder, I have added image column.Please look into that if condition.